# jQuery .remove() not working after using .prepend()

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am simply trying to create a function that allows me to add a div with content using jQuery `.prepend()` and then when that div is clicked it is removed using `.remove()`.

Prepend seems to work fine, but I am having trouble getting the `.remove()` to work on prepended divs.  It works fine on divs that were already present.

Could anyone possibly help me with where I am going wrong?

Here is my code:

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".DivAdd").click(function(){
        var thisDivItem = $(this).attr('add');thisDivItemid = "DivItem"+$(this).attr('add');
        $( ".DivItem" ).parent().prepend( "<div id='"+thisDivItemid+"' class='DivRemove')>"+thisDivItem+"</div> " );
    });
    $(".DivRemove").click(function(){ $( this ).remove() });
});
</script>

<div class="DivAdd" add="321">Div Add</div>
<div class="DivItems">
    <div class="DivItem DivRemove" id="DivItem1">1</div>
    <div class="DivItem DivRemove" id="DivItem2">2</div>
    <div class="DivItem DivRemove" id="DivItem3">3</div>
    <div class="DivItem DivRemove" id="DivItem4">4</div>
    <div class="DivItem DivRemove" id="DivItem5">5</div>
    <div class="DivItem DivRemove" id="DivItem6">6</div>
    <div class="DivItem DivRemove" id="DivItem7">7</div>
</div>
```

Comment: You need to use [event delegation](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/) like `$(document).on('click', ".DivRemove", function(){ $( this ).remove() });`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using:

```
$(".DivItems").on('click', '.DivRemove', function(){ $( this ).remove() });
```

As others have mentioned, [.on()](https://api.jquery.com/on/) refers to the concept of [event delegation](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/).

Comment: He would need to delegate the event. So more like: `$('.DivItems').on('click', '.DivRemove', function(){$( this ).remove()});`

Comment: Ah yes, overlooked the proper syntax. Thanks @JackPattishallJr.

Answer (score 2):

You need to delegate your event handlers. This is because the element is dynamically added, and not in the DOM at the time jQuery was initialized. So it's pretty much like jQuery doesn't know about this object. You can delegate the event handler on something that will exist at the time of page load. For example, if your appended div were inside of a wrapping div:

```
  $('.wrapper').on('click',".DivRemove", function() {
    //do stuff
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the principle of [`delegate()`](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/):

> *Attach a handler to one or more events for all elements that match the selector, now or in the future, based on a specific set of root
>   elements.*

```
$('.DivItems').delegate('.DivRemove', 'click', function(){ 
    $( this ).remove() });
});
```

Or you can use [`on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) for this, which is preferred:

```
$('.DivItems').on('click', '.DivRemove', function(){ 
    $( this ).remove() });
});
```

> *Delegated events have the advantage that they can process events from descendant elements that are added to the document at a later time. By
>   picking an element that is guaranteed to be present at the time the
>   delegated event handler is attached, you can use delegated events to
>   avoid the need to frequently attach and remove event handlers.*

Answer (score 0):

This will do what you need. This will bind to existing and dynamic elements added to the dom as well.

```
$(document).on('click','.DivRemove',function(){ $( this ).remove() });
```